# How to use function arguments from list for function call

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to do something like this

```
allowed_args = ['--email', '--password', '--verbose']

if '--email' in allowed_args:
    parser.add_argument('--email')
if '--password' in allowed_args:
    parser.add_argument('--password', help='Better dont use your password on command line')
if '--verbose' in allowed_args:
    parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
```

Because I will need to define, which arguments are allowed before parsing the arguments using `argparse`.

This works like expeted, but how can I avoid, using these repetitive if clauses (this is just an example, I would actually have a lot more...)? I would like somehow to predefine the arguments and then choose which of them to use.

Comment: Why not have a mapping of `allowed_args` with all the flags and parameters as a mapping, and iterate through the actual provided list to build the parser?  Also, what exactly is the problem being solved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky:

```
allowed_args = {
    '--email':{}, 
    '--password':{'help':'Better dont ...',}, # you can add more items
    '--verbose':{'action':'store_true',}
}
```

then:

```
for k,v in allowed_args.items():
    parser.add_argument(k, **v)
```

You can add as many as arguments to your `allowed_args` values(`the dict inside`).

Comment: I believe that the order might be important as this affects the order in which arguments are presented to the user with `--help`.  For sufficiently recent versions of Python, a dictionary is guaranteed to yield items in insertion order (I believe that it is only guaranteed since 3.6, although in fact the 3.5 implementation happens to be ordered). However, for compatibility with older versions, you might want to use a list of 2-tuples or an OrderedDict.

Comment: Yes @alaniwi, You are 100% right. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could write that like this:

```
for name, args, kwargs in \
    [('--email', [], {}),
     ('--password', [], {help: 'Better dont use your password on command line'}),
     ('--verbose', [], {action: 'store_true'})]:

    parser.add_argument(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

The mapping could also be stored in a dictionary, but by using a list of tuples, this ensures that options are added in the desired order even if used on older versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary of args and kwargs to pass in the event of a match:

```py
parameters = {
     "--email": {
         "args": [],
         "kwargs": {},
     },
     "--password": {
         "args": [],
         "kwargs": {
             "help": "Better dont use your password on command line"
         },
     },
     "--verbose": {
         "args": [],
         "kwargs": {
             "action": "store_true"
         }
     }
}
```

Then, you can iterate over your input array and add the parameters in a loop:

```py
allowed_args = ['--email', '--password', '--verbose']
for arg in allowed_rags:
    arg_parameters = parameters[arg]
    parser.add_argument(arg, *arg_parameters['args'], **arg_parameters['kwargs'])
```

You could also check whether the given parameter exists and raise an exception:

```py
    allowed_args = ['--email', '--password', '--verbose']
    for arg in allowed_rags:
        if arg not in parameters:
            raise NotImplementedError(arg)
        arg_parameters = parameters[arg]
```

Furthermore, if you use a set as input, you could avoid some edge cases:

```py
allowed_args = {'--email', '--password', '--verbose'}
for arg in allowed_args & parameters:
    arg_parameters = parameters[arg]
    parser.add_argument(arg, *arg_parameters['args'], **arg_parameters['kwargs'])
```